# Access violation at address * in module 'ntdll.dll'. Write of address *

Tags: c++, windows, c++builder

I'm writing a function that should find a file.

```
WIN32_FIND_DATAA* data;

HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile(name,data);//Access violation at address 76FC2373 in module 'ntdll.dll'. Write of address 00000008.
while(handle!= INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    FindNextFile(handle,data);
    result.push_back(data->cFileName);
    if(GetLastError())
        break;
}
FindClose(handle);
free(data);
```

I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FindFirstFile function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) expects the address of a WIN32_FIND_DATA structure. You were merely passing the value of an uninitiated pointer. It should be:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile(name, &data);
```

Be sure to remove the `free(data);` line as well (as `data` has not been allocated on the heap).

In addition, your current loop will skip the first file. You should use something like:

```
do
{
    if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) break;
    result.push_back(data.cFileName);
}
while (FindNextFile(handle, &data);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm doing something wrong?

[Yes.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA data;

HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile(name, &data);
```